# numbering some content of a file using grep or any other commands

Tags: linux, find, grep

I have a file like this:

```
==================================[RUN]===================================
result                : Ok
CPU time              : 0.016001 s

==================================[RUN]===================================
result                : Ok
CPU time              : 1.012010 s
```

i want to numbering RUNs like this

```
==================================[RUN 1]===================================
result                : Ok
CPU time              : 0.016001 s

==================================[RUN 2]===================================
result                : Ok
CPU time              : 1.012010 s
```

how can i do that using grep or any other commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '/^=+\[RUN\]=+$/ { i++; sub(/RUN/, "RUN "i) }1' file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -pe 'if (/=\[RUN\]=/) { $i++; s//=[RUN $i]=/; }'
```